# I cannot connect to DSN with Perl Win32:ODBC

Tags: windows, perl, ms-access

**Background:**
I am using Windows 10 and Perl v5.26.1. I inherited some Perl code that needs to connect to a database. This previously worked using Windows 7 and Perl 5.16.3.

The code is using Win32::ODBC to connect to the database. I get the following error:

> Connect failed: [911] [] "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application"

I am using a 64 bit version of Perl and trying to connect to a 32 bit MS Access database but I am assuming that Win32 is handling this. Also the same setup was working in the Windows 7 setup.

I am able to connect to the database using the ODBC Data Source Administrator.

As an attempt to determine the issue I tried:

```
use strict;
use Win32::ODBC;

print "DataSources\n";

my (%dsn, $key) = Win32::ODBC::DataSources();

foreach $key (sort keys %dsn) { 
    print "$key\n"; 
}

print "Done\n";
```

This resulted in

```
DataSources
Done
```

So I am not finding any DataSources. Running the same code on the Windows 7 machine does generate DataSources.

Running `Get-OdbcDsn` in Powershell generates a list of data sources.

**Question:**
Why am I not able to see DataSources using Perl in v5.26.1 using Windows 10?

Comment: What version of Office did you install 32 or 64 bit ?. Try running your perl code using a portable 32 bit version of Strawberry Perl. I have just downloaded strawberry-perl-5.30.1.1-32bit-portable and tested a connection successfully on Win10 64 bit, Access 32 bit with a 32 bit ODBC driver. With my 64 bit perl I get the same error as you.